# React history.push location.state is undefined on refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-routing

I am using history.push() to redirect to a page and passing some props like below:

```
const ViewDetailCellRenderer = (props: any) => {
  let history = useHistory();
  const scenario = props.data;
  const onButtonClick = (event: React.KeyboardEvent | React.MouseEvent) => {
    history.push({
      pathname: `/scenario-details/${scenario.ID}/kpi`,
      state: {
        scenario: scenario,
      },
    });
  };
  return (
    <Button color="secondary" label="View &rarr;" onClick={onButtonClick} />
  );
};
```

In the new page I am able to access the data using location.state. The problem I am facing is that on page refresh the location.state is undefined.  I am able to access the scenario id using props.match.params. Is there a better way to do this? My last option would be to use local storage but not sure if thats the best solution.

Comment: Hi you would have to use local storage. Location state is not something that is persisted.

Comment: Like @DanielDuong and yourself have said, you would need something like local storage to make this work. Depending on your application structure, an alternative method could be to pull the scenario data from a server using an api request with the scenario.ID part of the URL

Comment: Route state is very transient, it exists ***only*** for the route transition and receiving in the target. Without the route transition there is no route state to receive. Alternatives are the typical state storage models, but since these exist in memory you'll ultimately need to persist state to localStorage (*or similar*) where it can be retrieved when the app reloads/mounts.